# CONCAT() and DATE_FORMAT() gives different result in mysql for date range

Tags: mysql, date-format, concatenation

i am having trouble, when i use `CONCAT('2017-01-15', ' 00:00:00')` it gives different result than when i use `DATE_FORMAT('2017-01-15', ' %Y-%m-%d 00:00:00')` in MySQL for date range .. any idea please?

for example my query is

```
SELECT SUM(payments) as pays 
FROM   table 
WHERE  employee_id = 25 
AND    `date` >= DATE_FORMAT('2017-05-16', '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') 
AND    `date` <= DATE_FORMAT('2017-05-31', '%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59') 
GROUP BY employee_id 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

and with CONCAT

```
SELECT SUM(payments) as pays 
FROM   table 
WHERE  employee_id = 25 
AND    `date` >= CONCAT('2017-05-16', ' 00:00:00') 
AND    `date` <= CONCAT('2017-05-31', ' 23:59:59') 
GROUP BY employee_id 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Both gives different results ..

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: is 'date' a text field?

Comment: no date is DATETIME field

Comment: Different timezones maybe? Maybe you're passing values from your app which uses a different timezone than your MySQL server, and when the server creates a datetime with date_format, it's in the MySQL server's timezone? You should compare (and possibly provide here) the output of your concat and date_format functions.

Comment: no its not timezone issue i am pretty sure about it.. its something else .. script and mysql both are on same server using same timezone

Answer (score 0):

**I just noticed you have the leading space in the format string I copy-pasted.** Double check your actual queries for this.

[Disregard below]

It may be some strange casting issue, it appears that DATE_FORMAT (in the server I was testing on) includes a leading space.

This is the query I used to track down this strangeness if you're interested:

```
SELECT @t0 := '2017-01-15' AS t0, @tN := '2018-01-15' AS tN
, @df0 := DATE_FORMAT(@t0, ' %Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') AS df0, @dfN := DATE_FORMAT(@tN, ' %Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') AS dfN
, @ct0 := CONCAT(@t0, ' 00:00:00') AS ct0, @ctN := CONCAT(@tN, ' 23:59:59') AS ctN
, @df0 = @ct0 AS eq0, @dfN = @ctN AS eqN
, CAST(@ct0 AS DATETIME) = CAST(@df0 AS DATETIME) AS castsEqual0
, @ct0 = CAST(@df0 AS DATETIME) AS castDF0Equal
, CAST(@ct0 AS DATETIME) = @df0 AS castCT0Equal
, @n := CAST(now() AS DATETIME) AS n
, @n > @ct0 AS `n>ct0`, @n > @df0 AS `n>df0`
, @n < @ctN AS `n<ctN`, @n < @dfN AS `n<dfN`
, @n < CAST(@dfN AS DATETIME) AS `n<castDFN`
, CAST(@n AS CHAR) < @dfN AS `castN<dfN`
, LENGTH(CAST(@n AS CHAR)), LENGTH(@dfN)
, CONCAT('[', @dfN, ']')
;
```

Comment: leading space where ?

Comment: In the format string. `' %Y-%m-%d 00:00:00'` should be `'%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00'`. It looks correct in your examples, but the initial version you gave in your question has it.

Comment: i am grouping by date actually, i think date is doing some issue

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses guyz, actually i had issue in 23:23:59 :) it had to be 23:59:59 :) i didn't notice it somehow ..
Thanks - problem solved